# Why arc() function draw a line in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I try to draw multiple circles on a canvas and after I draw the first circle a horizontal line appear. Here is a print screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qramc.jpg.

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var distance_x_circle = 20;
        var distance_y_circle = 20;

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            context.arc(distance_x_circle, 20, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.stroke();

        distance_x_circle += 40;            


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your circles are considered one path, that's why you get that line. You can use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) to start a new path with each circle.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var distance_x_circle = 20;
var distance_y_circle = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(distance_x_circle, 20, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.stroke();

  distance_x_circle += 40;            

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=100></canvas>
```